# Setting up Dynamic Links in Firebase with Wordpress site

Tags: swift, wordpress, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, associated-domains

I am really struggling here... All I actually want to achieve is that I can get the **Generate-Strong-Password**  function inside my app but that is actually harder than I thought.

I learned that I should go with **Firebase Dynamic Links** because I have a **Wordpress-Website** from **All-Inkl.com**.

I followed [this Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0) and there is actually an `Apple-Site-Association-File` at the moment. But I can't access my [Website](https://wishlists-app.de/) anymore as it looks like this:

[image]

Inside my Firebase Project I am getting this error which says that there not all the necessary "A-Files" are inside my Website:

[image]

**My DNS-Settings:**

[image]

I've been struggling for weeks now to get this done so if anyone has any idea how I can fix it I would be extremely grateful!! (btw, I am a total newbie when it comes to websites; I know my way around Swift though)

Comment: You can refer to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest

Comment: @AbderazakAmiar not quite following you here. How exactly is this supposed to help me ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that different domain providers accept different values for DNS entries ('A records' = 'A-Datensätze', in this case).

Try editing the entries for the Host field (which currently hold your website's URL) to one of the 'common inputs' listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?hl=de#domain-key

As the URL to your site doesn't seem to be what your provider accepts, I would suggest you try replacing it with the next option, i.e. replacing it with `@` .

Hope this helps solving your issue!

Comment: the problem is that in **all-inkl** I can not set 2 A records for the domain, only one (last picture first line). Thats why I changed the Host-Fields to ' * ' . But these fields are not recognized by Firebase.